# nvcc 4.2 "ptxas error: illegal operand type to instruction 'ld'" when compiling to sm_20

Tags: cuda

sm_13 compiles fine, but sm_20 gives this error multiple times.  The PTX files are completely different between the different compile options.  Here is an example of an offending line from the PTX file:

```
ld.global.u32   %r1, [cudaTextureLeftSource_3D_UI8];
```

Comment: If this happens with pure HLL code (i.e. no inline PTX) it would appear to be a bug in the compiler frontend (the part that produces the PTX code), and the malformed PTX is then flagged as an error by the PTX parser of the compiler backend (which consumes intermediate PTX and compiles it into SASS machine code). At this point the easiest thing is probably to try compiling with CUDA 5.0 RC compiler to see whether the problem still occurs. If so, please file a bug. The PTX files look completely different because a different frontend (Open64) is used for sm_1x; other targets use NVVM frontend.